# Apache Spark hangs after writing parquet file to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using apache spark 1.3.1 with hadoop 2.6 libraries. I am also using the s3a protocol. My job reads data from an s3 bucket, parses it, and then writes a parquet file to another bucket. It works fine, except that the job hangs on completion and never exits. Any ideas on what causes this, is there a resource I need to close?

The code is very basic:

```
val log: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("s3a://whatever/txt")
val records: RDD[MyRecord] = log.flatMap(parse)
records.toDF.saveAsParquetFile("s3a://something/else")
logInfo("Done")
```

everything completes successfully, and then my job just hangs.

Comment: I have tried unpersisting the dataframe I create from my records, and stopping the SparkContext, but that does not help.

Comment: I also tried the s3n protocol, and that does work, but I have a lot of reliability problems with s3n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we fixed this issue by upgrading our hadoop-aws jar from 2.6.0 to 2.7.1